# How to use Azure Frontdoor with gRPC?

Tags: azure, azure-front-door

Azure Frontdoor is supporting HTTP/2 without any excludes, based on docs.
But how to configure FD?

I created a grpc container on Azure Container Instances, it works fine.
If I put the FD in front of the container, I always get TCP Read errors.

REST works fine the same way.
Did I miss something?

Answer (score 2):

This won't work currently.

There is a note in [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/frontdoor/front-door-http2):

> HTTP/2 protocol support is available only for requests from clients to Front Door. The communication from Front Door to back ends in the back-end pool happens over HTTP/1.1.